# how to get back existing msg queue id

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am using msgget() syscall to get new msg queue. I have used the IPC_CREAT & IPC_EXCL flags in that. like
`message_queue = msgget(ftok("/tmp", 100), (0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL));`
Now, when my prog exists unexpectedly, the msg queue remains and I am failed to re-create the msg queue. So, my question is "How can I get back the existing msg queues's ID ?"

and by the way, where does msg queue stores its id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regd "How can I get back the existing msg queues's ID ?"

From man msgget

```
   If  msgflg  specifies both IPC_CREAT and IPC_EXCL and a message queue already exists for key, then msgget() fails with errno set to EEX-
   IST.  (This is analogous to the effect of the combination O_CREAT | O_EXCL for open(2).)
```

Try without IPC_EXCL flag.

Regd. where does msg queue stores its id

from man proc

```
   /proc/sysvipc
          Subdirectory  containing  the  pseudo-files  msg,  sem  and  shm.  These files list the System V Interprocess Communication (IPC)
          objects (respectively: message queues, semaphores, and shared memory) that currently  exist  on  the  system,  providing  similar
          information  to that available via ipcs(1).  These files have headers and are formatted (one IPC object per line) for easy under-
          standing.  svipc(7) provides further background on the information shown by these files.
```

Comment: thnx for the reply **user967552**. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an attempt to answer the question, if it is useful, the credit should go to [The Linux Programmer’s Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg-0.4.pdf). If it is identified as irrelavant or something, the mistakes are all mine.

The ipcs command can be used to obtain the status of all System V IPC objects.

```
ipcs -q: Show only message queues
ipcs -s: Show only semaphores
ipcs -m: Show only shared memory
ipcs --help: Additional arguments
```

The ipcrm command can be used to remove an IPC object from the kernel. While IPC
objects can be removed via system calls in user code (we’ll see how in a moment), the need
often arises, especially under development environments, to remove IPC objects manually.

Its usage is simple:

```
ipcrm <msg | sem | shm> <IPC ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to *re-create* the message queue the second time. Your use of `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL` the second time is causing `msgget` to fail.

From man page of [msgget](http://linux.die.net/man/2/msgget)

> If **msgflg** specifies both **IPC_CREAT** and **IPC_EXCL** and a message queue
>   already exists for key, then **msgget**() fails with **errno** set to **EEXIST**.
>   (This is analogous to the effect of the combination **O_CREAT | O_EXCL**
>   for **open**(2).)

So you can still continue using `msgget` the second time, but use only the `IPC_CREAT` flag.
Also make it a point to check the return values of both `ftok` and `msgget` and compare the error values, if any, with the man page. Also check `errno`.

Also if you are having too much trouble with an existing message queue you can remove it with invoking `msgctl` along with `IPC_RMID` flag

Also, the other answer as to where the msg queues are stored. You migh be tempted to delete a troubling msg queue :) But mind you, they are read only files resting on a virtual file system /proc!

Comment: @JohnG Glad it helped you John! :)