# Check if a message queue exists

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I create a message queue in C like this:

```
int msgid; 
int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;

key_t key;

key = ftok(".",'a'); 
if ((msgid = msgget(key,msgflg)) < 0 ){
    syserr("msgget error");
}
```

How can I check if the queue already exists? And I don't want to create a new if already exists.

Comment: Take a quick read through answers on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10024211/804773   --- They talk about checking the errno and using flags to determine if you're attempting to access an existing queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the flag `IPC_EXCL` to [`msgget()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html) and if it fails and `errno` equals `EEXIST` then the queue exists.

```
int msgid = -1;
key_t key = -1;

if (-1 == (key = ftok(".", 'a')))
{
  perror("ftok() failed");
} 
else if (-1 == (msgid = msgget(key, IPC_EXCL | IPC_CREAT | 0666)))
{
  if (EEXIST == errno)
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "The queue exists.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    perror("msgget() failed");
  }
}
```